# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject error

Tags: asp.net

i am getting an error on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

i have Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my bin folder

here is my code:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Dim joContent As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(srReader.ReadToEnd)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: here is the detailed error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer' is not defined.

Source Error:

Line 119: Dim srReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(wrResponse.GetResponseStream)
Line 120: Dim jsJson2 As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer

Line 122: 'Dim joContent As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(srReader.ReadToEnd)

Source File: www.smartsimcha.somee.com\test\CreditCardForm1.aspx.vb Line: 120

Comment: Did you add a reference to the project?